# How to add custom action to yii\rest\activecontroller extended controller in yii2?

Tags: php, rest, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

i want to add login action in my controller ut its giving me page not found error.
i know there are many posts like this but no one has helped me yet.

code for my controller:

```
<?php
// controller for rest apis
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\rest\Controller;
use yii\web\Response;
//use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\UserMaster;

//class UserController extends Controller
class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\UserMaster';
    public $pluralize = false;
    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['contentNegotiator']['formats']['text/html'] = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return $behaviors;
    }
    public function actionLogin(){
        return UserMaster::find()->all();
    }
    public function login(){
        return UserMaster::find()->all();
    }       
}
?>
```

code from config/web.php:

```
 'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'class'=>'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'showScriptName' => false,

            //for specifying rest api model to be used
            //and by pluralize=false we can use with singular name rather than plural as default (users)
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'rules' => [
                [
                 'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                 'controller' => 'user',
                 'pluralize'=>false,
                 'extraPatterns' => [
                    'GET /user/login/' => 'login', // 'xxxxx' refers to 'actionXxxxx'
                  ],
                ]
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: why don't you use of  $behaviors['authenticator'] for use authentication? do you know about that?

Comment: Seems ok, just change 'GET /user/login/' to 'GET login' in extraPatterns. (Now it's trying to fetch from /user/user/login.)

Answer (score 2):

Let's begin right from the model:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

/**
 * My UserMaster model
 */
class UserMaster extends ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user_master'; // the name of the table 
    }

    // other code ...
}
```

Then the UserController.php will look something like this:

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use app\models\userMaster;

/**
 * My User controller
 */
class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    // define the model class
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\UserMaster';

    // add a serializer to make front-end development easier
    // public $serializer = [
    //     'class' => 'yii\rest\Serializer',
    //     'collectionEnvelope' => 'items',
    // ];

    // the login action
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        return UserMaster::find()->all();
    }
}
```

We then configure our urlManager as such:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => false,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [

        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
            'controller' => 'user', 
            // 'pluralize' => false
            'extraPatterns' => [
                'GET login' => 'login',
                // other patterns
            ]
        ],

    ],
],
```

Now we can make use of our login by visiting the URI `GET /users/login`. More details at [Yii2 REST Quick Start](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html)